# STL list and iterators

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Hello I just can't get it to work. I ahve structure with 4 members and I create list and iterator:

```
std::list<structure> one;
std::list<structure>::iterator two;
```

Now I want to get acces to element:

```
one.end-1;
two = one.end()-1;
```

it doesn't work >.> Compilator throws like 14 errors.

Errors go like:

All of them goes something like:

> Glowne.cpp(105) : error C2784:
>   'reverse_iterator<_RanIt>::difference_type
>   std::operator -(const
>   std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const
>   std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' :
>   could not deduce template argument for
>   'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt>
>   &' from
>   'std::list<_Ty>::_Iterator<_Secure_validation>'
>   with [ _Ty=Klient,
>   _Secure_validation=true ]

Everything working great, thanks for mentioning back method, really guys You are great.

Answer (score 6):

Bidirectional iterators (as used by `std::list`) do not support "pointer arithmetic", only single steps:

```
two = one.end();
--two;
```

Also, the statement `one.end-1;` has absolutely no effect at all, I would get rid of that.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the last element of a list, use the [`back()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/back/) member.

Answer (score 1):

List is not a random access container, that means you cannot use arithmetic operations on its iterators.

To move through the list you can use operators `++` and `--` to move the iterator by one element.
If you'd like to move to the arbitrary position, use something other, for example std::vector, instead.

Most of the containers have `front()` and `back()` method, for accessing first and last element.